# How to get around HttpResponseMessage (Request.CreateResponse) in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
protected HttpResponseMessage CreatedResponse(string routeName, object routeValues)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    var locationUri = Url.Link(routeName, routeValues);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(locationUri);

    return response;
}
```

Whats the equivalent code in .net Core? 
Or a way around it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `Controller.Created` method, but now it also requires information about URI:

```
public IActionResult CreatedResponse(object value)
{
     return this.Created(<string uri>, value);
     //or 
     return this.Created(<Uri uri>, value);
}
```

Actually, in background method creates and returns the [CreatedResult](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/CreatedResult.cs)  object, that is derived from `ObjectResult`, and fill `Location`, `Value`  and `StatusCode`  fields. So, as alternative, you may create general `ObjectResult` response if you don't need to return the URI.

```
public IActionResult CreatedResponse(object value)
{
    return new ObjectResult
    {
        Value = value,
        StatusCode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status201Created // 201
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I built upon the other answer, and created an extension method. You will have to return an IActionResult. So if you still want to do it the old fashion way, you can with this:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
  public static IActionResult CreateResponse(this HttpRequest request, int status, object content)
  {
    return new ObjectResult(content)
    {
      StatusCode = status
    };
  }
}
```

And in use:

```
public IActionResult Patch(long id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<SomeModel> value)
{
  //other code here for patching logic

  var response = new { Original = modelBefore, Patched = modelAfter };

  return Request.CreateResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK, response);

}
```